# Horizontal Tabs rendered as rendering collapsible fields

Tags: 7, entities

Although I have set up the a Content Type's display to use Horizontal Tabs

[image]

It's rendering as collapsible fields:

[image]

Does anyone have ideas on how to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In commons_origins theme's template.php file, fieldset default functions are overridden("function commons_origins_fieldset"), pls comment or remove it to have display as tabs. Or clone this theme as custom theme in sites/all/themes folder and create as new theme by removing this function.