# Field group horizontal tabs are displayed as accordions in small screens

Tags: 8, theming

On Drupal 8 site using the default Bartik theme, I have setup the article content type to be displayed in **horizontal tabs** based on the "field group" module.

On normal/large screens, the article display page is rendered in **horizontal tabs** style (Good!):

[image: Horizontal tabs display]

However, in small screens, the article display page is rendered in **accordion** style (Not good!):

[image: Accordion display]

I have found an answer here [Horizontal Tabs rendered as rendering collapsible fields](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85141/horizontal-tabs-rendered-as-rendering-collapsible-fields) which is for Drupal 7 and I didn't know how to convert it to work for Drupal 8.

Does anyone have an ideas how to keep the article display rendered as **horizontal tabs** for whatever screen sizes?

Comment: This should be reported on drupal.org, not here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps try out the patch to make this setting configurable as proposed for field_group module in [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group/issues/2998778)

Users have reported that it applies cleanly and allows for the setting to trigger based on a custom breakpoint.

Testing it out and reporting success/failure on that issue gives a better chance for this feature to be included into the module itself.

**NOTE:** the patch probably needs to be applied to the dev version of the field_group module

Comment: Thank you @GiorgosK for the link provided, but the patch does not apply for the Drupal 8.6.9

Comment: You must apply the patch to the dev verison of the module and not on the beta-1 version